# Ensure npm/pip dependencies are binary-preserved

Tags: npm, pip, package-managers

My company has a policy that all projects should not reference any 3rd party code servers after the release. Basically they ask to make local mirrors of all package servers. This is to ensure we can reproduce the release, given that it is always a risk that somebody will change the code on the server, not controlled by us, without changing the library version. It is also a security risk to blindly use external servers.

What is the proper way to fulfill this policy with `npm`? If I understand it correctly, `package-lock` is not enough - it will give me a warning if hash is changed, but I will not be able to reproduce the build.

There is `npm-mirror`, but it seems old and I was not able to run it. Are there better up-to-date alternatives?

Also, I was thinking about just preserving a copy of `node_modules`, but this doesn't really work. We are building our projects on different environments, and `node_modules` folder is environment specific and needs to be built separately for each.

We also use `python` and I would assume I need to find the solution for the same problem with `pip`